# Am I using the ternary operator?

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary

Here is my code:

```
echo "<option value=".$crew_rank_id.".(($crew_rank_id == $crew_rank) ? "selected" : "").>".$crew_rank_table."</option>";
```

what im trying to do is echo out the selected value from the database in `echo`

Comment: Yes, you are...

Comment: google it. Use this forum to ask questions regarding the problem you are facing. And for your question you are using ternary operatory but your `"` are not balanced

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are mixing PHP statements in a string and your quotes and HTML tags are misplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing PHP statements and PHP variables in the string and have some missing quotes and HTML-tags.

This should work:

```
echo "<option value='{$crew_rank_id}' ". (($crew_rank_id == $crew_rank) ? "selected" : "") . ">{$crew_rank_table}</option>";
```

Comment: man thanks. your code did work

Answer (score 0):

try this,
check `$crew_rank_id == $crew_rank` store in variable and assign to it in `<option>` tag

```
$selected = "";
if($crew_rank_id == $crew_rank)
{
    $selected = "selected";
}

echo "<option value=".$crew_rank_id.".$selected.>".$crew_rank_table."</option>";
```

Comment: your code don't have and error but it doesnt echo the correct value

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a double quotes in several places. The first one got the value and the "selected" to be one word, without spacing. The second before the closing of the option tag.

```
echo "<option value=".$crew_rank_id." ".(($crew_rank_id == $crew_rank) ? "selected" : "").">".$crew_rank_table."</option>";
```